# Empty list for hrefs to achieve pagination through JavaScript onclick functions

Tags: javascript, python, href, scrapy

My intension is to `achieve the pagination from javascript functions`, so for example I am taking the URL as `http://events.justdial.com/events/index.php?city=Hyderabad`, from this URL as you can see the pagination at the end of the page, so if you observe HTML of that they are written through JavaScript functions which has `href` tags as `#`, I am just trying to collect that href tags even though they are `#`.
The following is my code

```
class justdialdotcomSpider(BaseSpider):
   name = "justdialdotcom"
   allowed_domains = ["www.justdial.com"]
   start_urls = ["http://events.justdial.com/events/index.php?city=Hyderabad"]

   def parse(self, response):
       hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
       pagination = hxs.select('//div[@id="main"]/div[@id="content"]/div[@id="pagination"]/a').extract()
       print pagination,">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>."
```

When I run the above code I am getting the result as `[]`, I mean none,can anyone tell me how to achieve the pagination through that JavaScript onclick functions and why the result is empty.And I am observing some kind of wierd in HTML that for example one of the page in pagination has anchor tag as `<a onclick="jdevents.setPageNo(2)" href="#">2</a>`
but when I tried to view this by clicking `view page source`through browser I can't see any function as `jdevents.setPageNo(2)`, (I expect if we can see what he is doing in HTML we can post that through formdata as request) I am really confused and unable to go through this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you tracked the requests, you'll find post requests to the following URL :
http://events.justdial.com/events/search.php

Post Data :

```
city:Hyderabad 
cat:0 
area:0 
fromDate: 
toDate: 
subCat:0 
pageNo:2
fetch:events
```

and the response is in JSON format.

So, your code should be the following

```
import re
import json

class justdialdotcomSpider(BaseSpider):
    name = "justdialdotcom"
    domain_name = "www.justdial.com"
    start_urls = ["http://events.justdial.com/events/search.php"]


    # Initial request
    def parse(self, response):
        return [FormRequest(url="http://events.justdial.com/events/search.php",
                                        formdata={'fetch': 'area',
                                                  'pageNo': '1',
                                                  'city' : 'Hyderabad',
                                                  'cat' : '0',
                                                  'area' : '0',
                                                  'fromDate': '',
                                                  'toDate' : '',
                                                  'subCat' : '0'
                                                  },
                                        callback=self.area_count
                                        )]


# Get total count and paginate through events
    def area_count(self, response):
        total_count = 0
        for area in  json.loads(response.body):
            total_count += int(area["count"])

        pages_count = (total_count / 10) + 1

        page = 1
        while (page <= pages_count):
            yield FormRequest(url="http://events.justdial.com/events/search.php",
                                        formdata={'fetch': 'events',
                                                  'pageNo': str(page),
                                                  'city' : 'Hyderabad',
                                                  'cat' : '0',
                                                  'area' : '0',
                                                  'fromDate': '',
                                                  'toDate' : '',
                                                  'subCat' : '0'
                                                  },
                                        callback=self.parse_events
                                        )
            page += 1


# parse events 
    def parse_events(self, response):
        events = json.loads(response.body)
        events.pop(0)

        for event_details in events:
            yield FormRequest(url="http://events.justdial.com/events/search.php",
                                        formdata={'fetch': 'event',
                                                  'eventId': str(event_details["id"]),
                                                  },
                                        callback=self.parse_event
                                        )



    def parse_event(self, response):
        event_details = json.loads(response.body)
        items = []
        #item = Product()

        items.append(item)
        return items
```

Comment: After executing the parse method, it should send a response to area_count by calling it, but here parse is not sending any response to area_count,i got this when i printed the response in area_count nothing happening...

Comment: Actually spider is working fine until parse method but not entering in to area_count method, if we write wrong code in area_count method, its not displaying an error