# Empty list returning by xpath in scrapy

Tags: python, list, xpath, scrapy

I am working on scrapy , i am trying to gather some data from a site ,

**Spider Code**

```
class NaaptolSpider(BaseSpider):
    name = "naaptol"
    domain_name = "www.naaptol.com"
    start_urls = ["http://www.naaptol.com/buy/mobile_phones/mobile_handsets.html"]

    def parse(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        cell_matter = hxs.select('//div[@class="gridInfo"]/div[@class="gridProduct gridProduct_special"]')
        items=[]
        for i in cell_matter:
               cell_names = i.select('//p[@class="proName"]/a/text()').extract()
               prices = i.select('//p[@class="values"]/strong/text()').extract()
               item = ExampleItem()
               item['cell_name'] = cell_names
               item['price'] = prices
               items.append(item) 
        return [FormRequest(url="http://www.naaptol.com/faces/jsp/search/searchResults.jsp",
            formdata={'type': 'cat_catlg',
            'catid': '27',
            'sb' : '9,8',
            'frm' : '1',
            'max' : '15',
            'req': 'ajax'
            },
            callback=self.parse_item
            )]

def parse_item(self, response):
     hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response) 
     cell_matter = hxs.select('//div[@class="gridInfo"]/div[@class="gridProduct gridProduct_special"]')
     for i in cell_matter:
               cell_names = i.select('//p[@class="proName"]/a/text()').extract()
               prices = i.select('//p[@class="values"]/strong/text()').extract()
               print cell_names
               print prices
```

**Result:**

```
2012-06-15 09:38:36+0530 [naaptol] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <POST http://www.naaptol.com/faces/jsp/search/searchResults.jsp> (referer: http://www.naaptol.com/buy/mobile_phones/mobile_handsets.html)
[]
[]
```

Actually i had posted the form to achieve the pagination which is in javascript

Here i am receiving the response from parse method in parse_item method, but when i used the xpath same as in parse method its returning an empty list as above, can anyone tell me why its returning an empty array, and whats wrong in my code.

Thanks in advance

Comment: @Dennis: sorry i had edited my code,cell_matter contains the output something like this

Comment: [<HtmlXPathSelector xpath='//div[@class="gridInfo"]/div[@class="gridProduct gridProduct_special"]' data=u'<div class="gridProduct gridProduct_spec'>, <HtmlXPathSelector xpath='//div[@class="gridInfo"]/div[@class="gridProduct gridProduct_special"]' data=u'<div class="gridProduct gridProduct_spec'>, <HtmlXPathSelector xpath='//div[@class="gridInfo"]/div[@class="gridProduct gridProduct_special"]'.........]

Comment: but for the cell_matter in parse_item is [], i am using the same xpath because in page when we click on pagination he is posting the values just by changing the form so the xpath should work i think

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The response is in JSON format:

```
{
  "prodList": [
    {
      "pid": "955492",
      "pnm": "Samsung Star 3 Duos",
      "mctid": "27",
      "pc": "5,650",
      "mrp": "6290",
      "pdc": "10",
      "pimg": "Samsung-Star-3-duos-1.jpg",
      "rt": "8",
      "prc": "1",
      "per": "Y",
      (...)
    },
    (...)
}
```

In order to parse it, you can use python's json module. An example of what you are trying to achieve is here: [Empty list for hrefs to achieve pagination through JavaScript onclick functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10975337/empty-list-for-hrefs-to-achieve-pagination-through-javascript-onclick-functions).

Comment: Thanks for u r reply, my intension is to achieve pagination in that and parse those pages, now how can i achieve that, because even though posting the values i am unable to get the result......