# exceptions.ValueError: unsupported format character in python scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

Hi i am working on scrapy

Below is my code

```
class examplespider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "example"
    domain_name = "www.example.com"
    start_urls = ["http://www.example.com/sch/mobile-/67939/i.html?_catref=1"]

def parse(self,response):
    hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
    for i in xrange(1,10):
        yield Request(url="http://www.example.com/sch/mobile-/67939/i.html?_catref=1?_trkparms=65%253A12%257C66%253A1%257C39%253A1%257C72%253A3276&rt=nc&_catref=1&_dmpt=IN_Mobile_Phones&_trksid=p3286.c0.m14.l1513&_pgn=%d"%i,
                                 callback=self.parse_item)
def parse_item(self,response):
    print response,"Here it is................."
```

**Result:**:

```
    File "/home/local/username/project/example/example/spiders/example_spider.py", line 117, in parse
    yield Request(url="http://www.example.com/sch/mobile-/67939/i.html?_catref=1?_trkparms=65%253A12%257C66%253A1%257C39%253A1%257C72%253A3276&rt=nc&_catref=1&_dmpt=IN_Mobile_Phones&_trksid=p3286.c0.m14.l1513&_pgn=%d"%i,
                                 callback=self.parse_item)
    exceptions.ValueError: unsupported format character 'A' (0x41) at index 61
```

Can any one tell me whats wrong is code and why unsupported format character code error is displaying, whether url is not supported here,also when we supply a a single integer without format specifier i can able to get response. 
please let me know the above,

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your URL contains many unescaped `%` symbols and you're trying to interpolate a value into the string using the `%` operator. Python is looking for `%` characters to substitute your `i` into the URL. But the first likely one it sees is `%A` and that's not a valid format character. The error message even tells you exactly what has happened and where.

Probably the easiest general solution is to use the `.format()` method of the string instead of the `%` operator:

```
("http://www.example.com/sch/mobile-/67939/i.html?_catref=1?"
 "_trkparms=65%253A12%257C66%253A1%257C39%253A1%257C72%253A3276&rt=nc"
 "&_catref=1&_dmpt=IN_Mobile_Phones&_trksid=p3286.c0.m14.l1513&_pgn={0}").format(i)
```

It uses different formatting placeholders that don't conflict with your URL's use of the `%` character.

Or, in this case specifically, since you just want to append your variable to the URL, you could use straight-up concatenation:

```
("http://www.example.com/sch/mobile-/67939/i.html?_catref=1?"
 "_trkparms=65%253A12%257C66%253A1%257C39%253A1%257C72%253A3276&rt=nc"
 "&_catref=1&_dmpt=IN_Mobile_Phones&_trksid=p3286.c0.m14.l1513&_pgn=") + str(i)
```

Comment: Hurray that worked thanks very much i am very clear about the second one about string concatanation, but in first solution "l1513&_pgn={0}", actually here what happens if l1513&_pgn={i}, sorry really i dont know the concept can u please let me know it.

Comment: Also here the loop is repeating for 10 times, and for some responses the result is 2012-06-15 13:03:32+0530 [spi] DEBUG: Redirecting (301) to <GET http://www.example.com/sch/mobile-/67939/i.html?_catref=1?_trkparms=65%253A12%257C66%253A1%257C39%253A1%257C72%253A3276&rt=nc&_catref=1&_dmpt=IN_Mobile_Phones&_trksid=p3286.c0.m14.l1513&_pgn=7> from <http://www.example.com/sch/mobile-/67939/i.html?_catref=1?_trkparms=65%253A12%257C66%253A1%257C39%253A1%257C72%253A3276&rt=nc&_catref=1&_dmpt=IN_Mobile_Phones&_trksid=p3286.c0.m14.l1513&_pgn=3>,why it is redirecting here

Comment: The `{0}` in the `format()` example means to use argument 0, i.e. the first argument, which is `i`.

Answer (score -1):

I think problem is what you mark in your string interpolation i as integer but its string or something another, try check type of i.

Comment: @Dennis: Actually i had wierd doubt,i know that i should not ask here, so i created a new post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11045510/empty-list-returning-by-xpath-in-scrapy , can u please have a look at it